# Variable Speeds on CHECKDB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, dbcc-checkdb

Does anyone know why I should experience variable CHECKDB completion times from day to day? I'm seeing times anywhere from 45 to 90min for the task to complete.

I am running CHECKDB on 8 SQL Server databases comprising of about 350Gb worth of data. I run the checks nightly at 11PM using a Maintenance Plan.

Comment: Are there other things running, any difference in that? Like backups - Index optimization - ... ?

Comment: There are other scripts running on the same server, but they run nightly at the same time. There's no differences between what I'm running on the faster nights vs. the slower nights.

Comment: Is the storage on a SAN, shared with other hosts?

Comment: The storage is on a SAN. The SAN storage is divided between a bunch of different VMs (which are hosted on local hardware). One of those VMs is the server hosting our SQL Server.

Comment: I know I am not answering your question. I hope [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2007/01/24/checkdb-part-7-how-long-will-checkdb-take-to-run/) article will lead you to identify your issue.

Comment: How about measuring the latency for your SAN (from the SQL/VM perspective) and compare if that differs a lot? Also, watch out if other jobs that does heavy modifications "bleed into" the CHECKDB. When modifications are performed at same time as CHECKDB, CHECKDB basically has to do double its work (sort of, due to db snapshot).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi That's a good idea. I'm sure that is somewhat variable from day to day, which may be causing it. It also could have to do with our daily ETL scripts being variable from day to day - they run at the same time, but depending on how much data was generated in a particular day, they could be taking longer and/or be dumping more data into the DBs.